# How to handle in Hibernate multiple table entities that share the same composite id in the database?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

My main table has a composite primary key where one of the fields is a sequence. It has a one to one relationship to two other tables where the composite key is the primary/foreign keys of those respective tables. In my java code, I have a PK class which contains a `@SequenceGenerator`. Since the columns are shared between the tables, I tried having my entities all use the same PK class. However, since my PK class has a field that has a `@SequenceGenerator`, whenever I try to insert into the foreign key tables, hibernate is generating an additional sequence and is failing on the insert due to the parent key not being found.

Since the `@SequenceGenerator` was generating an additional sequence for subsequent inserts into the other tables, I cloned my PK class for each other table and removed the `@SequenceGenerator` so the columns were the same and hibernate wouldn't generate a new sequence during insert. This however created another issue where hibernate is expecting a different PK class than the one that is being provided.

```java
public class AddrEntityPK implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long addrTyId;
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ADDR_SEQ", sequenceName = "ADDR_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ADDR_SEQ")
    private long addrSeqNum;
}

public class PhoneEntityPK implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long addrTyId;
    @Id
    private long addrSeqNum;
}

public class ElecrMailEntityPK implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long addrTyId;
    @Id
    private long addrSeqNum;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(AddrEntityPK.class)
public class AddrEntity {}

@Entity
@IdClass(PhoneEntityPK.class)
public class PhoneEntity {}

@Entity
@IdClass(ElecrMailEntityPK.class)
public class ElecrMailEntity {}
```

Since the column names are the same I would expect hibernate to not generate an exception but it instead throws `org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provide id of the wrong type for class AddrEntity. Expected AddrEntityPK, got class PhoneEntityPK`

Comment: The *general* property fields and methods are not much relevant to the problem, but id fields and the relationship fields associating the entities with each other are of prime importance, especially since it's not clear to me from the entity names or ID classes what the nature of the relationships would be.

Comment: With that said, I suspect the best answer probably involves switching from `@IdClass` to `@EmbeddedId`, and engaging [`@MapsId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) appropriately.  The latter is the mechanism for handling the general scenario you describe, where an entity's identity is defined in whole or in part by a one-to-one relationship with another entity.  Switching to `@EmbeddedId` is a prerequisite for using `@MapsId`.

Comment: Will `@SequenceGenerator` and `@GenerateValue` work within `@EmbeddedId`?

Comment: I'm not sure.  (If I were, I'd be writing an answer instead of comments.)  I suspect that it *will not* work to annotate a field in the @Embeddable class with `@Id` or `@GeneratedValue`, but you should be able to put those annotations on the fields of the main entity instead.  You should also be able to use the `@Embeddable` class as an `@IdClass` for the main entity (without embedding it on that side).

Comment: So just moving the `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` to the main entity seemed to do the trick. I did not even need to add the `@Embeddable` annotation to my PK class. Thanks for your help!